# Transform pandas series to array

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a dfseris of type  `pandas.core.series.Series` with this shape:

```
0     [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0 ...
1     [0, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...
2     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...
3     [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0 ...
```

I would like to have a numpy array:

```
array([[[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ] ...
```

I have tried:

```
pd.DataFrame(dfseris.to_list()).to_numpy()
```

Though it works well in Jupyter in my code it is given this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'` says `dfseris` is not a series but a dataframe.

Comment: Yes indeed in the code file it is a  `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` now question is why it is another in the jupyter notebook...

Comment: I will reformulate the question .

Comment: Looks like  you have a Series which has arrays (or lists) as elements.  Series do have some form of `tolist`, `values` or `tonumpy` (you can find the exact name in the docs), but I expect the result will be a 1d object dtype array. You may be able to use `np.stack` to combine those elements into one 2d array.